# Задача питон реплит

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, python-2.x, сетевое-программирование

Пользователь вводит количество элементов списка. С помощью цикла
создается список со случайными элементами от 1 до 100. Ответом будет являться
сумма соседних элементов от максимального по размеру элемента.
Если максимальный по размеру элемент первый или последний, то указать
ответом его соседа ([33, 5, 12] -> ответом будет 5).

Comment: ты ошибся, тут не сервис по решению твоих задач

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

n = int(input("Введите количество элементов: "))
lst = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(n)]

max_index = lst.index(max(lst))  # индекс максимального элемента
if max_index == 0:
    answer = lst[1]
elif max_index == n - 1:
    answer = lst[-2]
else:
    answer = lst[max_index - 1] + lst[max_index + 1]
```